# Inject Kendo Dialog ViewRef via Contructor

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have an Angular multi-module application which makes heavy use of Kendo components.

I would like to create a single dialog that I can inject into any component I need it in. Here's an attempt to explain what I want.

```html
<app-root>
    <div kendoDialogContainer #appDialog></div>
    <kendo-drawer-container>
       <!-- application content, can ultimately go several layers deep -->
    </kendo-drawer-container>
</app-root>
```

```js
@Component({
// all the component configuration stuff
    standalone: true
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private dialogContainer : ViewRef, private dialogService : DialogService) {}

    someFunction() : void {
        this.dialogService.open(
            // dialog details, title, content, etc,
            appendTo: // the appDialog
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I see is that the dialog will be an ancestor to whatever component wants to make use of it. So, this ultimately turns into "How do I reference an ancestor component?"

Thanks for any help.